# Blender throws keyframe error when exporting as gltf (glb) file with animations - Key.path_resolve could not be resolved

Tags: blender, gltf

I am pretty new to blender, animations and gltf. I have successfully created my 3d model and was able to export that as glb file. Currently, I am trying to add a walking animation but the export to gltf with animations doesn't work. This is the error that the exporter is throwing:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 575, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 46, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 63, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 72, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 39, in gather_gltf2
    animations += __gather_animations(blender_scene, export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 83, in __gather_animations
    animations_, merged_tracks = gltf2_blender_gather_animations.gather_animations(_blender_object, merged_tracks, len(animations), export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animations.py", line 76, in gather_animations
    animation = __gather_animation(blender_action, blender_object, export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animations.py", line 114, in __gather_animation
    channels=__gather_channels(blender_action, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animations.py", line 150, in __gather_channels
    blender_action, blender_object, export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 65, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_channels.py", line 83, in gather_animation_channels
    None)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_channels.py", line 202, in __gather_animation_channel
    sampler=__gather_sampler(channels, blender_object, export_settings, bake_bone, bake_channel, bake_range_start, bake_range_end, action_name, driver_obj),
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_channels.py", line 263, in __gather_sampler
    export_settings
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 65, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_samplers.py", line 65, in gather_animation_sampler
    bake_bone, bake_channel, bake_range_start, bake_range_end, action_name, driver_obj, export_settings),
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 65, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_samplers.py", line 240, in __gather_input
    export_settings)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 65, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_sampler_keyframes.py", line 240, in gather_keyframes
    step
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 90, in wrapper_bonecache
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_animation_sampler_keyframes.py", line 177, in get_bone_matrix
    drivers_to_manage = get_sk_drivers(obj_driver)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 117, in wrapper_skdriverdiscover
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Applications\Blender\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_drivers.py", line 54, in get_sk_drivers
    sk_name = child.data.shape_keys.path_resolve(get_target_object_path(sk_c.data_path)).name
ValueError: Key.path_resolve("key_blocks["Key 1"]") could not be resolved

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I suppose that the gltf exporter can't find my keyframes, but I have no clue on how to fix that issue.
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted a bug report for the gltf exporter. You can look at it here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1401
Removing invalid drivers fixes the issue.