# Python error while exporting blender 3d model

Tags: 3d, blender, gltf, 3d-modelling

I have blend file with a 3d model developed .When I try to export that model as gltf, I get python error.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace.

Comment: Is this just a model or some animation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745143/blender-throws-keyframe-error-when-exporting-as-gltf-glb-file-with-animations) or could it be how you created the model (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163721/exporting-to-gltf-doesnt-work-properly)

Comment: Try turning on the Blender "Console" window to be able to copy-and-paste this large error message.  The last few lines are the most important for us to see.